# jquery adding class on load

Tags: jquery

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.text').load(function() {
        if (this.value == this.title) {
            $('.text').addClass("highlight");
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.highlight
{
  background: #FFA9B8;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML

```
<label for="first_name">first name: </label>
<input type = "text" name = "first_name" class = "text" value = "First..." title = "First..." />
<label for="last_name">last name: </label>
<input type = "text" name = "last_name" class = "text" value = "Last..." title = "Last..." />
```

I essentially want to add the class "highlight" to the background of the 2 input fields when the page is loaded...only when both the title and value are the same.

Thank you
-Art

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.text').filter(function(){
        return this.value === this.title
   }).addClass('highlight')
});
```

Comment: I think you need a semi-colon after the end of the return statement and the end of the addClass() but otherwise should work.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss semi-colon is optional in JS.

Comment: Sometimes, my comments should have indicated "to pass jslint" add semi-colons in the noted places.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Yes, most of the times. jslint is another story.